# list error using ggmap route function

Tags: r, ggplot2, routes, mapping, ggmap

So Im trying to use ggmap's route() function to create a geom that i can overlay onto a map.

I have a list of locations listed in "lat, lon" format in a list called checkpoints.

```
list("40.775912, -74.012619", "40.775912, -74.012619", "40.782669, -74.008143", 
"40.788587, -74.000447", "40.805952, -73.991671", "40.821177, -73.987895", 
"40.836634, -73.978271", "40.845806, -73.971319", "40.855106, -73.967628", 
"40.859186, -73.972037", "40.862502, -73.969255", "40.863977, -73.968383", 
"40.860894, -73.968126", "40.856154, -73.972603", "40.852727, -73.965511", 
"40.850897, -73.965913", "40.850939, -73.968064", "40.846506, -73.970819", 
"40.836634, -73.978271", "40.821177, -73.987895", "40.806622, -73.991894", 
"40.788587, -74.000447", "40.782669, -74.008143", "40.775912, -74.012619")
```

Im trying to perform the route function on each set of locations in order i.e from 1-2 then 2-3...

```
   routes <- lapply(2:length(checkpoints),
             function(x) route(from = checkpoints[[x-1]],
                               to = checkpoints[[x]],
                               mode = "driving",
                               output = "simple"))
```

The code runs up until the 10th step every time then I get this error:

```
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
```

I wind up with a list of 10 entries of the route data the way i want it then nothing else.  Ive tried unlisting the checkpoints list in the apply function and it still doesn't get past the 10th step for whatever reason.  Any help would be appreciated.  Also please excuse any errors in format or decorum, this is basically my first question.

Comment: seconding @Axeman, I'd include a data set for us to look at here; you might also print out the 10th column and see what's special about it. finally; in cases like this I always recommend cheating; force the list into a data table a la checkpoints  <- as.data.table(as.character(checkpoints)) and then give it another go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't very informative, but I think this is because there are limits on how often you can call Google's API for this kind of information. We can limit our call rate with a sleep command, which makes it work ok:

```
lapply(2:nrow(checkpoints),
       function(x) {
           Sys.sleep(1)
           ggmap::route(from = checkpoints[[x-1]],
                         to = checkpoints[[x]],
                         mode = "driving",
                         output = "simple")
           } )
```

Also note that you can only do so many queries a day, which you can check with `ggmap::routeQueryCheck()`.